# DataFormatConversion.InvalidSchema using hyphen/dash in AWS Glue and Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have this CloudFormation Glue template that includes a hyphen in one of the struct fields:

```
  TestGlue:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: testdatabase
        Name: 'test'
        StorageDescriptor:
          Location: "s3://testpath"
          Columns:
            - Name: test
              Type: struct<testcol:string,item-testcol:string>
```

This table is used for Kinesis Firehose record transformation, but whenever I try to send data for processing, I got this error below. Is there a way to enforce dash or hyphen, so far I cannot change this to underscore because current data uses hyphens and there would be a lot of impact.

```
"lastErrorCode":"DataFormatConversion.InvalidSchema","lastErrorMessage":"The schema is invalid. Error parsing the schema: Error:: expected at the position XX of 'struct<testcol:string,item-testcol:string>' but '-' is found."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Glue Data Catalog is running on the Hive Metastore, I don't think it's possible to use the dash in the names.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll use Column to mappings

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Robert also, Glue doesn't support using 'hyphens' in the column names.

From the Glue documentation:

```
When you create schema in AWS Glue to query in Athena, consider the following:

- database name cannot be longer than 252 characters.
- table name cannot be longer than 255 characters.
- column name cannot be longer than 128 characters.
- The only acceptable characters for database names, table names, and column names are lowercase letters, numbers, and the underscore character.
```

Please refer the [Glue best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-names) for more details.